# react native .then(() => {

Tags: listview, react-native, pull-to-refresh

I would like to implement a Pull-to-Refresh into a ListView in React Native.

...

```
_onRefresh() {
        this.setState({refreshing: true});
        this._refreshData(this.course).then(() => {
          this.setState({refreshing: false});
        });
      }
```

....

```
_refreshData(course) {
    this.props.dispatch(clearLectures());
    this.props.dispatch(fetchLectures(course));
  }
```

....

```
  return (

          <ListView
            dataSource={dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(lectures)}
            renderRow={this._renderRow}
            renderSectionHeader={this._renderDayHeader}

            refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl
              refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
              onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
              />
            }

          />

    );
```

....

I get the following error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

Do i have to implement some sort of return in the _refreshData function or is it another problem?

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: make your _refreshData function async so that it can return promise

Answer (score 0):

When the error is "Cannot read property 'property_name' of undefined" what you have to do is understand what is undefined?

So what you are doing is something like "this.undefined.then".

this._refreshData doesn't return anything so you are calling then on undefined. this._refreshData should return something who has then as a property: I think you need to return a Promise.

Something like:

```
_refreshData(course) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //get data
        // resolve(data) or reject(error)
    }
}
```

I don't know how you implemented your store and your components, so I cannot say something more.

Maybe this [link](https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/returning-promises-from-redux-action-creators-3035f34fa74b) could help you.